# Symfony- routing error

Tags: php, symfony, class

I got an error..

> (1/1) ClassNotFoundException
>   Attempted to load class "BaseApiController" from namespace "Project\Api\Controller".
>   Did you forget a "use" statement for "Project\Admin\Api\Controller\BaseApiController"?

My routes

```
admin:
resource: '@ProjectBundle/Admin/Front/Controller/'
host: %admin_domain%
type: annotation
app:
resource: '@ProjectBundle/Controller/'
type: annotation
admin_api:
resource: '@ProjectBundle/Admin/Api/Controller/'
type: annotation
prefix: '/admin/api'
fundstar_api:
resource: '@ProjectBundle/Api/Controller/'
type: annotation
prefix: '/api'
```

My Controller..

```
<?php
namespace Project\Api\Controller;
use Project\Admin\Api\Controller\BaseApiController;
```

`class BasicController extends BaseApiController {}`

and it says

> Exception thrown when handling an exception (Symfony\Component\Config\Exception\FileLoaderLoadException: Cannot load resource "/var/www/html/app/config/routing_dev.yml".)

and in my routing_dev file

```
_wdt:
resource: '@WebProfilerBundle/Resources/config/routing/wdt.xml'
prefix: /_wdt
_profiler:
resource: '@WebProfilerBundle/Resources/config/routing/profiler.xml'
prefix: /_profiler
_errors:
resource: '@TwigBundle/Resources/config/routing/errors.xml'
prefix: /_error
_main:
resource: routing.yml
```

Comment: Is your routing_dev.yml stored in `/var/www/html/app/config/`?

Comment: Its /var/www/project-platform/app/config/routing_dev.yml

Comment: Well.. the error says "Cannot load resource var/www/html/app/config/routing_dev.yml", because it's apparently not there.